# Rate limit of authenticated git API request

Tags: github

I'm using authenticated Git API request using access token. But still, I get the request rate limit 60 req/hr. But the document says, for authenticated requests the rate limit is 5000 req/hr. Why I'm getting 60 req/hr. or is there any wrongs in curl comment which I'm using?

Eg: 
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "authToken: xxxxxxx" -i https://api.github.com/repos/d3/d3/git/refs/tags/3.5.3"

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax for sending the OAuth Token is wrong. You need to use either this format

curl -H "Authorization: token xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" https://api.github.com

(or)

curl https://api.github.com/?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Reference:
https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication

Answer (score 0):

Well as per git documentation which says :

> For unauthenticated requests, the rate limit allows for up to 60
>   requests per hour. Unauthenticated requests are associated with the
>   originating IP address, and not the user making requests.

But if you needs to make unauthenticated calls with a higher rate limit, you can pass your app's client ID and secret as part of the query string.

Eg :

```
curl -i 'https://api.github.com/users/whatever?client_id=xxxx&client_secret=yyyy'
```

Please refer to link for further information :
[the unauthenticated rate limit for OAuth applications](https://developer.github.com/v3/#increasing-the-unauthenticated-rate-limit-for-oauth-applications)